# Access elements of structure within structure in the weird JSON response using ColdFusion

Tags: json, facebook, coldfusion, structure

Could anyone please advise how one would access id or name elements within these nested structures using ColdFusion?

Just a note, this is deserialized JSON response from Facebook's Graph API.

Thanks!

[image: structure example]

Comment: `structname['thefullurlthatIcantcopypaste']['id']`

Comment: Thanks @MattBusche, that did it! If you'd add this as an answer I could accept it providing you with points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference any key using the notation below.

`structName['fullurlname']['id']`